# Prevent user from going back to the previous secured page after logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am facing an issue in MVC that i am able to visit the previous page on browser back button click even after getting logged out. I have few approaches:

1) Disable the Browser back button using `window.history.forward()`.
This will give bad user experience.

2) Using `outputCacheAttribute` by providing the `duration=0` but this will restrict both server side and client side caching. SO don't want to use this.

3) Adding below method in `global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

Third approach will not allow to make the copy of the cache to the browser. Also to make this work I have to add the **`[Authorize]`** attribute on each controller.
This is not the best option for me as I have hundreds of controller. And tomorrow if I will add new controller then again I have to decorate the **Authorize** attribute to that new controller.

Is there any other approach that any one of you can suggest.

Comment: Downvote seems unfair, reasonable question. In online banking apps and payment providers such as Worldpay I have sometimes pressed back and seen a message saying 'please do not press back, click here to start again'

Comment: Found any solution? Currently using the javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add this attribute:

```
 [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
 Public ActionResult SomeAction()
 {
    //
 }
```

Disabling cache in specific action should be enough I guess.

> Or if you still do not want to destroy cache just couple of places,
>   you can do that in your LOGIN function, you can add previous Attribute, or just use this when someone signs out:

```
       Session.Clear();
       Session.Abandon();
```

I wish it will help, since I havent got much time on testing it myself.

Comment: Hi, suggested approach is not working. I don't to disable the catching. Let me know if there is any other approach to achieve the same.